# Use DATEDIFF function with mySQL

Tags: mysql, datediff

Just try to use the DATEDIFF native function in SQL with my following query:

```
SELECT 
    KDX_Id, 
    (
        SELECT DATEDIFF('DAY', ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI, ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO)
        FROM ___Bookings
        WHERE KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) AS nb_nights
FROM  ___Kardex
```

Error message is:
`#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'`.

Table structure is: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25399/2

What I am missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your MySQL version.

Comment: `SELECT DATEDIFF(date1, date2);` looks the way this function is working.

Comment: The error is self explanatory

Comment: See [MySQL DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

Comment: It appears that you're familiar with SQL Server's DATEDIFF function, which takes three arguments. MySQL's DATEDIFF only takes two arguments. Get rid of `'DAY',` and you should be good. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MySQL docs:

[DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in **days** from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

- DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)

Use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(___Bookings.BOO_DateCI, ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO)
```

Comment: I've now this error: `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d3c4c/1.

Comment: @rony datediff should return one record. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d3c4c/12

Comment: What function should I use if I need to sum all the datediff returned?

Comment: I mean, you cannot use an scalar subquery that returns more than one row, if not you should JOIN it

Comment: I can't use something like this `SUM(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(...))` ?

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    KDX_Id, 
    (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(___Bookings.BOO_DateCI, ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO)
        FROM ___Bookings
        WHERE KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) AS nb_nights
FROM  ___Kardex
```

Answer (score 0):

try this structure.

> SELECT DATEDIFF(date_1, date_2) FROM my_table;

```
 /*In your script is */
SELECT DATEDIFF(___Bookings.BOO_DateCI, ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO)
FROM ___Bookings
WHERE KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId;
```